# Using a non-5v analogReference voltage in the ADK2012

Tags: arduino, adk, atmega

I have a the ADK2012 arduino due-like device. I am using google's copy of the arduino software, and I can compile and run various sketches without trouble.

I've got an LM35 that I've hooked up to an analog input. By default, the reference voltage is 5 volts. This seems to work fine, but I would like to use a different analogReference value, as documented here:

http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/AnalogReference

Unfortunately, I'm having some trouble. When I use `DEFAULT` or `EXTERNAL` like this:

```
analogReference(DEFAULT);
```

I get this when I compile:

```
AnalogReadSerial.cpp: In function 'void setup()':
AnalogReadSerial:12: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'eAnalogReference'
AnalogReadSerial:12: error: initializing argument 1 of 'void analogReference(eAnalogReference)'
```

If I try to set it to `INTERNAL`, `INTERNAL1V1`, or `INTERNAL2V56`, I get errors like:

```
AnalogReadSerial.cpp: In function 'void setup()':
AnalogReadSerial:12: error: 'INTERNAL' was not declared in this scope
```

I'm at a bit of a dead end here. I'm not familiar enough with Arduino or Wiring to know if this is a problem with the supplied device configuration, or an actual limitation of the physical hardware, or a bug or incompatibility internally.

It's unfortunate that the hardware I'm using is relatively rare, and doesn't seem to have much documentation. I'd appreciate suggestions on where to start looking to fix this issue.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with the code, but couldn't you just use a voltage divider to make the incoming voltage max at 5V?

Comment: No. I'm attempting to change the reference voltage used internally by the chip, so that the range on the ADC better matches my input voltage. As-is, I'm throwing away approximately 4/5ths of my resolution since my signal will never exceed ~1v but the ADC is scaled to 5v.

Comment: I see, even with a common emitter amplifier circuit you wouldn't get great accuracy.  http://webpages.ursinus.edu/lriley/ref/circuits/node4.html#SECTION00044000000000000000 A software change is probably the way to go.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out (now that the arduino docs have caught up, 5 months later) that the answer is:

These devices operate at 3.3 volts natively, and so the `analogReference` function isn't enabled.

> The Due’s analog inputs pins measure from ground to a maximum value of 3.3V. Applying more then 3.3V on the Due’s pins will damage the SAM3X chip. The analogReference() function is ignored on the Due.

http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardDue

Answer (score 0):

It seems that analogRefence() expects a something like enum as argument

and the the definitions in arduino.h is a int

do you have the latest arduino ide (rev 1.0.1)

I've made a toolchain for arduino, and linked that to another ide, (netbeans)
so debugging the arduino core is quite simple.

haven't found the bug, (it works in the latest arduino ide);

anyway, for the arduino mega (ADK) you can do this in the new ide,
if this works, then you have selected the wrong board (tools>>board>>arduino mega2560 or mega ADK)

```
analogReference(0); //EXTERNAL
analogReference(1); //DEFAULT
analogReference(2); //INTERNAL1V1
analogReference(3); //INTERNAL2V56
```

Comment: I'm using google's toolchain as detailed here: http://developer.android.com/tools/adk/adk2.html#dev I'm not sure how to get their files working in the standard arduino ide...

Comment: The device I have is NOT an arduino mega, because I am developing with the ADK 2012, not the ADK 2011.

Answer (score 0):

Arduino 2 doesn't permit EXTERNAL reference.
You will find this in the SAM library (...sam\cores\arduino\wiring_analog.h ):

```
typedef enum _eAnalogReference
{
    AR_DEFAULT,
} eAnalogReference ;
```

And external is not permitted.

Answer (score 0):

The µC use always external refernce, but is Hardware connected to 3.3V, if you want to use AREF you can change a 0-Ohm resistor on the board.